# Comparision between A select statement and Multiple select statment that act as batch

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sql-execution-plan

I have a stored procedure that contains some Select statements that return union result of them.

I think and write one select instead of several Select and want to compare EXECUTION PLAN of them (SP and one Select statement).

the problem is when run this twe statement(SP and Select) all select statement in sp have their execution plan.I want to have execution plan of SP as an UNIT.

I have another question.Consider execution plan that attached to this post.Is sum cost of an execution plan for all statement must be 100%?

But why sum cost of all statement of this execution plan not be 100%?

[Execution plan](http://www.filefactory.com/file/ca5907c/n/ExecutionPlan.sqlplan)

thanks

Comment: Can't access your execution plan, is your total greater or less than 100%?  and how much is it off by?

Comment: I can't access your execution plan either and I'll be damned if I'll create a "free" rapidshare account to get to it. Most likely you have an acount and didn't consider this to be a problem but you might be dismissing a lot of volunteers to help.

Comment: @Lieven:I changed it again.Please try

Comment: sorry no luck. 1.A lot of advertisement. 2.Download Now 3.Wait 30 seconds. 4.Download link at bottom of page 5.paste link into browser 6 goto 1. *a good reminder to myself why I hate these kind of sites with a passion*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to compare two versions of the logic then a script along the lines of:

```
Exec <storedProc>

Select <data> From <tables>
```

Will let you do it.  Yes the execution plan will show you all of the queries inside the stored proc.  Look for the plans for the queries that occur outside of the SP.  If they give a total cost > 50% then the SP performed better.

As a side note, if your SP takes parameters make sure you compare the execution plans across a range of parameter values.

Comment: I change link for execution plan you can download it now

Answer (score 0):

A `UNION` is several select statements.  You are essentially saying "Show me the results from this query, joined with the results from this query, joined with the results from this query..."  How else will SQL Server get the results from those queries without executing them?

Comment: I want cost execute of SP as an unit.not cost all select inside of sp

Comment: @Nima - then rewrite it as one `SELECT` statement.  If you have multiple `SELECT`s it's not a single unit.  SQL Server has to execute it independently.